# Error when trying export from Mysql to CSV

Tags: mysql, database, csv

When I trying to export Mysql DB to CSV like `SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/test.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM reviewdb1;`
I get error

> ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected

However I sign reviewdb1 properly.
So I switch to reviewdb1

```
 mysql> use reviewdb1
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/test.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM reviewdb1;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'reviewdb1.reviewdb1' doesn't exist
```

and it seems like something wrong in my query (syntax)
Could you give me advice, what exactly ?

Thanks in advance.

Update:
it's dawn on me I should sign TABLE in the DATABASE which I want to export to .csv.

```
SELECT * FROM account_diff_preferences INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/test.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

this command works fine, but may I export whole database like this or only one table from database per command accepted ?

Comment: Is reviewdb1 the table name AND the database name?

Comment: Why do you think there's something wrong with your syntax? The error message is very clear about what the problem is: there's no table named `reviewdb1` in the database named `reviewdb1`.

Comment: Type `show tables` to see the list of table names.

Answer (score 0):

now I realize it was pretty stupid question.
excuse me.